# System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Me esta surgiendo este problema el cual no he logrado resolver, me tira el siguiente error "System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto" esto en la vista de un listar en el "foreach (var item in model). también coloque un break point y veo que el médoto

```
  ListaDeClientes = elCordinador.ListarTodosLosClientes();
        return View(ListaDeClientes);
```

retorna null;

Comment: A mi casi siempre que me sale ese error es porque no he instanciado algo o porque algo tiene un valor null . Deberia poner mas codigo para  analizar mejor.

Comment: Puedes dar más información? Qué tipo de variable es ListaDeClientes; en dónde la declaras?

Answer (score 0):

el error te dice que estás tratando de acceder a un objeto "Nulo".
Te recomiendo que leas y te familiarices sobre como inicializar https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors

Debido a que no sé qué tipo de datos tiene tu variable `ListaDeClientes` una alternativa es utilizar `var` para declarar e inizializar en una sola sentencia.

```
var ListaDeClientes = elCordinador.ListarTodosLosClientes();
        return View(ListaDeClientes);
```

Nota importante: si utilizas esto, debes de borrar el lugar donde declarabas la variable ListaDeClientes, para que no te de error.